# Lisp/Scheme/Racket: How to define a function with ellipsis

Tags: function, scheme, racket, variadic-functions, arity

I want to define a function in Racket with undefined number of arguments so I use ellipsis, but it doesn't work:

```
(define (f x ...) (printf x ...))
(f "~a ~a" "foo" "bar")
```

Error:

```
Arity mismatch
```

How to define a function in Racket with ellipsis?

Comment: Tip: such a function is called “a variadic function”.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two halves of this:

1. accepting an arbitrary number of inputs
2. passing an arbitrary number of arguments to another function

To accept an arbitrary number of inputs, instead of a `...` after `x`, put a single `.` before `x`. This declares `x` as the "rest" argument, and the arguments will be collected into a list for `x`.

Example:

```
> (define (f . x) x)
> (f "~a ~a" "foo" "bar")
(list "~a ~a" "foo" "bar")
```

To pass an arbitrary number of arguments, you can use the [`apply`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/application.html#%28part._apply%29) function, which accepts a list as the last argument.

Example:

```
> (apply printf (list "~a ~a" "foo" "bar"))
foo bar
```

Putting these together:

```
> (define (f . x) (apply printf x))
> (f "~a ~a" "foo" "bar")
foo bar
```